# Ext JS Licensing browser Offline cached

Tags: extjs

We are developing a product with SaaS model and browser Offline cached most of the time.

And like to use Ext Js. Should we need to buy multiple licence for all users?

Comment: This is surely not a programming question, but Ext-JS licenses are not per application or number of users, they're per developer. http://www.sencha.com/store/extjs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha uses Developer licence model and you deploy as many users and with many application.

Buy licence only how many developer working ExtJS.